# SVN Checkout to other folder

Tags: svn

I am using this commant dor SVN checkout:

```
svn checkout http://svn/myandroid/DM-AndroidStable --non-interactive --username usr --password 123
```

But I wish to check out to other folder than DM-AndroidStable, to DM-AndroidTest

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is quite easy and it looks like this

```
svn co url://some/url name-of-directory-you-want
```

So for your example it should be something like

```
svn checkout http://svn/myandroid/DM-AndroidStable DM-AndroidTest --non-interactive --username usr --password 123
```